# ArrayList's add(index,object) method throw IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, collections

On creating an arrayList using the below mentioned code snippet:

```
List arrayList = new ArrayList(16);
```

The internal implementation of ArrayList creates an array `elementData` of size 16 and assigns `null`at every location. On doing something like `arrayList.add(2,"HelloWorld")` gives an **`IndexOutOfBoundException`** as the index at which the element is being added (i.e 2) is greater than the **`size`** attribute of the `arrayList` .

As clear from the javaDocs, the **`size`** attribute of the arrayList is initialized to 0 when the `arrayList` is initialized and is incremented by 1 everytime a new element is added to the `arrayList`

Can someone please explain, why the **`ArrayList`** dataStructure was designed this way in the first place. Even tho' the internal dataStructure **`elementData`** was initialized with 16 null values at the creation of arrayList, still it does not allow to add value at indeces > size; (assuming index <16 in this case). What was the idea to implement the add(index,object)
funtionality to be governed by the size attribute of the arrayList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of having an internal array with a size greater then List.size() is to avoid re-allocating the array unnecessarily. If the internal array always had the same size as the List, then every time a new element is added, the internal array would have to be re-allocated, causing a performance penalty.

Comment: But then why the arrayList does not allow to store values at indeces > size attribute?

Comment: Sinply because the List implementations do not allow it. A List should not be seen as simply a wrapper around an array. It's a separate data structure. Just because it uses an array internally, it does not mean that the same operations can be performed on it.

Comment: But isn't that specific to `LinkedList` and not List in general?

Comment: No, look at  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29. The javadocs specify that the `set` method should throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is larger than `size()`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the default constructor of ArrayList constructs a list with an initial capacity of 10.

```
public ArrayList() {
    this(10);
}
```

But why we need such an allocation? As you understand, if you indicate the size of ArrayList in advance, you can provide efficient for the list. Otherwise, after the number of elements exceeds the initial capacity of ArrayList, a new reallocation operation is performed for each element.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-) says:

> public void add(int index, E element)
>
> **Throws:**
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException -
>   if the index is out of range
>   (index < 0 || index > size())

As you can see, it throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if (index > size()).
Since ArrayList's "public int size()" returns elements which are not equal to null, your size equals to 0 (not 16 as you said in your example). In other words, if null values were counted as well, the size of each ArrayList that was created with default constructor would be 10.

Consequently, "arrayList.add(2, "HelloWorld")" throws IndexOutOfBoundsException since index = 2 but size() = 0.

Edit:

I think when you mount your argument, you use this as base:

```
String[] arr = new String[5];
arr[3] = "hello";

System.out.println(arr[3]);
```

Then, you think why you can give a value in an array element directly but why you cannot do the same thing while using add(int index, E element) method of ArrayList. Actually, it is true but there is no condition to implement ArrayList as complete counterpart of Array. In other words, this method is conditioned with that rule since it is nature of ArrayList. As we all know, when you create an array, you specify its size in square brackets. The constructor of ArrayList which takes int as parameter does not do the same thing. It performs just an imaginary allocation. Yes, it could specify its initial size with this allocation or after add(int index, E element) is called, size could be increased by one. However, ArrayList is implemented to provide an array-like structure which has continuity with respect to index number but has no fixed size. Thence, there are some other higher level of abstraction examples do this task. To exemplify, LinkedHashMap structure.

Comment: @Arslan: If the only purpose that this check is serving is to correctly return the number of elements in the arrayList, this could have been achieved without throwing the exception too. As the size attribute is being incremented on every `add()` call; It will always return the number of elements in the arrayList irrespective of the index location of the elements being inserted.

Comment: I wrote the definition mentioned in the official documentation. Yes, it throws in those conditions. I could not understand your argument exactly.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear; As you've mentioned (citing the javadoc) that the size attribute is used to count the number of  non null values in the `arrayList` (considering the default 10 size `elementData` internal array); My question is as the size is being incremented on the addition of elements to `arrayList` only (irrespective of the location; size will be incremented inb both the cases if I `add(3,"hello")` or `add("hello")`) why my `add(index,object )` is governed by the rule that `index < 0 || index > size()` ?

Comment: The size is increased by one with add("hello") since this method adds an element sequentially. I edited my answer, see above please.

Comment: @Arslan: Beautifully explained +1. 
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can not add object at a specific index till it contains null. You just need to add object using add method and then you can update values on a index.

For Example.

```
 ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

// use add() method to add elements in the list
arrlist.add(15);
arrlist.add(22);
arrlist.add(30);
arrlist.add(40);

// adding element 25 at third position
arrlist.add(2,25);
```

Answer (score 0):

You rarely need to specify the *capacity* of an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), it can improve the performance only if you know how many elements your `ArrayList` will hold.

`ArrayList` is simply a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) that can automatically be grown or shrink. Using `List`, you *never* need to add an element in the place `n` if the list is empty, you simply *link* it to the previous node (unless it's the head of course) - that's the idea of `ArrayList` except the fact that it can be grown/shrink automatically.

Comment: Even if we do not specify the initial `capacity` of the arrayList, it assumes an initial capacity of 10 which means an array (`elementData`) of size 10 is already created ; but does not allow to add the elements directly at indeces > size. On the other hand if I create an array of size 10 directly I can set value at any index in the array (but not in arrayList)

Answer (score 0):

See the java doc of `ArrayList`'s [add(int index,
       E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) method. Here you can find the `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception occurred when `if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())`.

You declared an `ArrayList` with an initial capacity 16. It doesn't mean that each of the 16 indexed position of the `ArrayList` contains element. It just mention the initial capacity and when it necessary it will grow it's size dynamically.

See the source code the constructor from the `ArrayList` class  -

```
/**
     * Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.
     *
     * @param   initialCapacity   the initial capacity of the list
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException if the specified initial capacity
     *            is negative
     */
    public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super();
        if (initialCapacity < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                               initialCapacity);
           this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
    }
```

Here we can not find anything that told us - `ArrayList` will initiated with null value.

**Update:** Based on your comment I have done some experiment, since I'm not sure about whether an array of reference/non-primitive type will initialized with null. See the following code below. Run the the code by uncommenting each of line at per execution -

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListTest{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); //default with initial capacity 10
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(5);
        List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>(5);

        list2.add(null);
        list2.add(null);
        list2.add(null);

        list3.add("zero");
        list3.add("one");
        list3.add("two");

        //System.out.println(list1.get(4)); //IndexOutOfBoundException

        //System.out.println(list2.get(0)); //null
        //System.out.println(list2.get(2)); //null;
        //System.out.println(list2.get(3)); //IndexOutOfBoundException

        //System.out.println(list3.get(0)); //zero
        //System.out.println(list3.get(2)); //two;
        //System.out.println(list3.get(3)); //IndexOutOfBoundException
        //list3.add(4, "four"); //IndexOutOfBoundException

    }

}
```

Here you can see `list2.get(0)` and `list2.get(2)` gives you null. Because we put null at these index. But `list2.get(3)` doesn't give `null` since we didn't put `null` at index 3. So it seems array of reference/non-primitive type won't initialize with `null`. `list2.get(3)` gives `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

You found the same scenario for the `list3.` where I didn't put any `null` in this list. Even when we are trying to add some value at index 4 of `list3` it gives `IndexOutOfBoundException`. Since the index 4 is not available for the `list3`. But you can add some value at index 2 of `list2`. Cause at index 2 of this list I have inserted `null` manually.

So in long story short (I think) - `new ArrayList<SomeType>(givenSize)` wouldn't initialize an array with `givenSize` with all element setting to `null`.

Hope it will Help.
Thanks.

Comment: The statement  `this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];` will create an array of size as defined by the **initialCapacity** with all the slots being initialized to null. This is the default behavious while creating objects for non-primitive types.

My question is, even if we have an array having the underlying datastructure being initialized why can't we set values at any location ?
 Correct me if am missing anything!!

Comment: @Sumit, I have done a small experiment, since I was not sure about this. You can see **update** portion. It seems `new Object[initialCapacity]` won't create an array of size with `initialCapacity` with all these slots being initialized to null. But If an array is initialized with null (which have to done manually) then we can set value at that position. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As mentioned in the problem statement; everytime an operation(**add** or **get**) is performed on an **index** which is greater than the **size** attribute; an `IndexOutOfBoundException` is thrown (which is similar to the behavior that your program is showing). The underlying array (elementData) in the `ArrayList` is initialized with 10 null values (in default capacity case ofcourse); which you can verify by debugging the `ArrayList` code as well.